# How to stop people from downvoting other correct answers on fairly easy questions?

Tags: discussion

Recently, I am seeing this trend where people hunt for easy questions, answer them quickly and then go on downvoting all other answers for that question which were even correct, in order to create an impression to the OP that their answer was the most valid one and should be accepted!

This is really annoying and totally against the spirit of SE where people try putting others down in order to gain more reputation.

Many a times this strategy works too, because the OP definitely hesitates to accept the answer having a negative score.

What do we have to prevent this kind of behaviour?

Comment: We already dis-incentivise the behaviour by locking in votes; the old strategy was to downvote then to reclaim your reputation loss (-1 per answer downvote) by undoing your vote when you got enough of a head start.

Comment: On the whole the best way to remedy this is to write better answers and let the *rest* of the community do the voting. Better answers float to the top, regardless of a FGITW strategical downvote.

Comment: In my experience, this doesn't happen all that much though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Best strategy?

Give a really good answer. Just because the answer is easy for you does not mean it is easy for others. In my experience - if you give a good explanation too and not just a code answer then you will always get upvotes.

Comment: Yes agree! Will keep it in mind next time!

Comment: The problem is that people may hesitate to upvote you if you already have a minus one. They may not even read your answer.

Comment: That is what I have mentioned in my question. The only way out here seems to be to give a really good meaningful answer as suggested by @juergen d

Comment: This is not a solution. There is no way you should lose reputation just because somebody writes a "better" answer later.

Answer (score -8):

I think that there may be a very good reason why slashdot allows you to either vote or comment, but not both.

So, perhaps on stack exchange people should at least not be allowed to downvote a competing answer.

Comment: So if I know an answer is wrong I can either comment saying so or provide the correct answer myself but not both.

Answer (score -9):

This is really a big matter that requires serious attention:

Downvoting not only happens on the answers as you mentioned, but also in questions that have been asked by newbie users.

Let us to see the brief pros and cons of Downvoting:

- It is usefull as it can suggest that the answer is not really usefull/helpfull and it is better to skip this; But when it comes to question downvoting,It is harder to say in this way.
- It is killing the motivation of the person who did the effort answered the question, or may ask the question; downvoting question is not good if you don't give a reason why you are doing so. Each question should be ask doesn't matter how silly it is, it might be not silly for the person who asked.

Conclusion
Downvoting and upvoting is made audience job easier to just skip the ones with low score,and find the best question and answer by seeing the number of upvotes.However the downvoting system is problematic and need reconsideration;Downvoting without giving reason can kill motivation of the person who asked or answered.

Comment: If downvoting demotivates those people who provide poor quality answers that's all to the good